# Terminal font color turned black [MacOS]

Tags: visual-studio-code

Terminal font color turned black in Visual Code running on MacOS Mojave

When using a dark theme I cant read text in the terminal since it's still black instead of turning to a light color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load a syntax theme. From the View menu at top of VScode screen click on extensions. That opens a sidebar with a list of all extensions. In the search box at the top of this sidebar type in "Themes Syntax". What you want to do is select a Syntax Theme. You'll want a dark syntax theme. This will color your fonts for a dark theme. If this doesn't work or you just want a single color theme then try the method in the next paragraph.

Go to settings and add, to the right-hand side, the variable name "terminal.foreground:". Type in a color like "#00ff00" for green. A small box filled in green will pop up. When this happens you can use your mouse to hover over your value (#00ff00) and a color picker will appear allowing you to enter the color you want for the font. I hope this was clear. If not please drop a comment and I will try to clarify it.